# Ravana - Who were his parents and siblings?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, vibhishana

Who were the parents of Ravana?

What were the names of Ravana's brothers and sisters?

And who is the real king of Lanka? Ravana or Vibhishana?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ravana's parents were Vishrava (son of Pulastya) and Kaikesi (daughter of Sumali and Thataka). Kaikesi had two brothers Maricha and Subahu which would effectively make them Ravana's uncles.

Ravana had six brothers and two sisters:

**Kubera** – the King of North direction and the Guardian of Heavenly Wealth. He was an older half-brother of Ravana: they were born to the same father by different mothers.

**Vibhishana** – A great follower of Rama and one of the most important characters in the Ramayana. As a minister and brother of Ravana, he spoke the truth without fear and advised Ravana to return the kidnapped Sita and uphold Dharma. Ravana not only rejected this sane advice, but also banished him from his kingdom. Vibhishana sought protection from Rama, which was granted without hesitation.

**Kumbhakarna** – One of the most jovial demons in Hindu history. When offered a boon by Brahma, he was tricked into asking for eternal sleep. A horrified Ravana, out of brotherly love, persuaded Brahma to amend the boon. Brahma mitigated the power of the boon by making Kumbhakarna sleep for six months and being awake for rest six months of a year (in some versions, he is awake for one day out of the year). During the war with Rama, Kumbhakarna was untimely awakened from his sleep. He tried to persuade Ravana to open negotiations with Rama and return Sita to him. But he too failed to mend the ways of Ravana. However, bound by a brother's duty, he fought on the side of Ravana and was killed in the battlefield. Before dying he met Vibhishana and blessed him for following path of righteousness.

**Khara** – King of Janasthan.  He protected the northern kingdom of Lanka in the mainland and his kingdom bordered with the Kosala Kingdom, the kingdom of Rama. He was well known for his superior skills in warfare.he was killed by Rama.

**Dushana** – Viceroy of Janasthan.

**Ahiravan** – King of the Underworld ruled by the rakshasas by Ravana and Demon King Maya.

**Kumbhini** – Older sister of Ravana and the wife of the demon Madhu, King of Mathura, she was the mother of Lavanasura. She was renowned for her beauty and later retired to the sea for penance.

**Surpanakha** – The sister of Ravana. She was the ultimate root of the kidnapping of Sita. She was the one who instigated her brothers to wage a war against Rama.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana#Ravana.27s_family)

Comment: Kumbhini/Kumbhinasi (wife of Madhu) was not Ravana's real sister. This is what Vibhishana himself says in UTTARA KANDA: "There was an old Rakshasa, celebrated for his wisdom, named Malyavan,the elder brother of Sumalin. our maternal grandfather. His grand daughter is Kumbhinasi and is born of our maternal aunt Anala ;so she is virtually our sister." -http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-30

Answer (score 6):

Rāvaṇa was born to [Viśravā](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/1/36) (father) and Kaikasī (mother, a.k.a [Keśinī](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/1/37)).

[This chapter](http://ramayana.tigercoder.com/07uttara/uttara_009.html) of Uttarakāṇḍa of Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa narrates the birth of Rāvaṇa, his two brothers Kumbhakarṇa & Vibhīṣaṇa, and his sister Śūrpaṇakhā.

From [this](https://sladeviper777.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/lord-ravanas-family-tree/) blog, here's Rāvaṇa's family tree:

[image]

You can find his other family members' details in the [Puranic Encyclopedia](https://archive.org/stream/puranicencyclopa00maniuoft#page/644/mode/2up) under the name Rāvaṇa.

---

#### Who is the real king of Laṅkā? Rāvaṇa or Vibhīṣaṇa?

Before Rāvaṇa, his stepbrother Kubera [ruled](http://ramayana.tigercoder.com/07uttara/uttara_011.html) Laṅkā. After Rāvaṇa was [killed](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga108/yuddhasans108.htm#Verse18) in the war, Rāma [instructs](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga112/yuddhasans112.htm#Verse9) Lakṣmaṇa to install Vibhīṣaṇa as the new king.

Comment: The chapter doesn't mention khara, dushana,kumbhini. abhiravan. There are some stories like thousand faced ravana too.

Comment: @SreeCharan Yeah, I don't know how Khara-Dushana are born. In my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12423/2995), you can see Rāvaṇa sends widowed Śūrpaṇakhā to stay with Khara-Dushana in the Dandaka forest.

Comment: @SreeCharan For 1000-faced Ravana, see [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14717/2995).

Comment: Khara dushana were mentioned in VR. So I believe that. But some blogs, I don't trust them. They publish some stories where the source is not mentioned. Yes. It is mentioned in parasara samhita too. Many stories which are not included in VR, about hanuma are there in parasara samhita.

Comment: @SreeCharan You have English version of Parasara Samhita?

Comment: There is sanskrit version available on the internet. It is yet to be translated into english. [Here](http://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskritupload/parAsharasamhitAhanupatcharitra1.pdf) is vol1 and [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiT27aa0e3QAhXMtY8KHTisAooQFggmMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.scribd.com%2Fdoc%2F44572934%2FSri-Parasara-Samhita-Part-II-%25E0%25B0%25B6-%25E0%25B0%25B0%25E0%25B1%2580-%25E0%25B0%25AA%25E0%25B0%25B0%25E0%25B0%25BE%25E0%25B0%25B6%25E0%25B0%25B0-%25E0%25B0%25B8%25E0%25B0%2582%25E0%25B0%25B9%25E0%25B0%25BF%25E0%25B0%25A4-%2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49950/discussion-between-sree-charan-and-sv).

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes, I know Telugu and Sanskrit versions are available. Was looking for English tr.

Comment: Kumbhini/Kumbhinasi (wife of Madhu) was not Ravana's real sister. This is what Vibhishana himself says in UTTARA KANDA: "There was an old Rakshasa, celebrated for his wisdom, named Malyavan,the elder brother of Sumalin. our maternal grandfather. His grand daughter is Kumbhinasi and is born of our maternal aunt Anala ;so she is virtually our sister." -http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-30

Answer (score 6):

> **Who were the parents of Ravana?**

The parents of Rāvaṇa were Viśravas and Kaikasī. Viśravas is the son of Pulastya Brahma, one of the mind born son of the creator Brahma.

> **What were the names of Ravana's brothers and sisters?**

The lineage of Viśravas is explained in detail in Chapter 8 of Upodghata Pada of Brahmanda Purana.

> 38-40: Viśravas married Devavarṇinī, the daughter of Brihaspati, Puṣpotkaṭā and Vākā, the daughters of Mālyavān, Kaikasī, the daughter of  Mālin. Listen to his children begot of these. Devavarṇinī gave birth to Vaiśravaṇa the eldest son.
>
> 44-46: On seeing him, his father said "This is Kubera(the ugly bodied one)". He was Kubera on account of his deformed body. He was thus marked by his name. Since he was the son of Viśravas and also due to his resemblance, he would be known by the name Vaiśravaṇa.
>
> 47. Kaikasī gave birth to Rāvaṇa, Kumbhakarṇa and śūrpaṇakhā, a daughter. Vibhīṣaṇa is the fourth among her children.
>
> 55-56. Mahodara, Prahasta, Mahāpārśva and Khara were the sons of Puṣpotkaṭā. She had a daughter (named) Kumbhinasī. Also Triśiras Dūṣaṇa and Vidyujjihva the Rākṣasā are remembered as the sons of Vākā. There was a daughter named Anupālikā.
>
> 57. Thus these ten Rākṣasās, the descendants of Pulastya, were of very cruel activities. They were of very terrible pursuits ever since their birth. All of these were unassailable even to the devas.

Hence from the above excerpt of Brahmanda Purana, it is clear that Rāvaṇa had thirteen siblings(10 brothers and 3 sisters). They were:

1. Kubera
2. Kumbhakarṇa
3. śūrpaṇakhā
4. Vibhīṣaṇa
5. Mahodara
6. Prahasta
7. Mahāpārśva
8. Khara
9. Kumbhinasī
10. Triśiras
11. Dūṣaṇa
12. Vidyujjihva
13. Anupālikā

From verse 57, we know that only ten of these are of cruel activity and other four are not. But it is not mentioned who are those cruel descendants.

> **And who is the real king of Lanka? Ravana or Vibhishana?**

Before Rāvaṇa, Kubera was the king of Lanka. After Rāvaṇa's death in the war, Vibhīṣaṇa [was installed](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga112/yuddha_112_frame.htm)  as the king of Lanka.

Comment: Is this from the Ramayana?

Comment: From Brahmanda Purana. Ramayana doesn't give much details about Ravana.

Comment: It's hard to believe that Prahasta was a brother of Ravan.

Comment: Yeah. They are all step brothers. We also find the mention of other demons in the Ramayana.

Comment: Did u consider brother-in-laws, cousins also as siblings???

Comment: Kumbhini/Kumbhinasi (wife of Madhu) was not Ravana's real sister. This is what Vibhishana himself says in UTTARA KANDA: "There was an old Rakshasa, celebrated for his wisdom, named Malyavan,the elder brother of Sumalin. our maternal grandfather. His grand daughter is Kumbhinasi and is born of our maternal aunt Anala ;so she is virtually our sister." -http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-30

Comment: @YDS Sibling: Each of two or more children or offspring having one or both parents in common; a brother or sister. I gave you the Brahmanda Purana verse which says Kumbhinasi is the daughter of Puṣpotkaṭā. I am not the one who wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, it is also important to trace the lineage of Kaikasi to understand Ravana's adharmic actions.

A Pishacha (wicked ghostly cannibal) named Aj had a daughter named Jantudhanaa. She married Rakshasa (fierce cannibalistic younger son of Kashyapa and Khashaa) and had a daughter named Yatudhana. In turn, Yatudhana gave birth to Heti, Praheti and 8 others [Ref: Brahmanda Purana Upodghaata paada 7.43-90]. All her descendants are called Yatudhana-Rakshasas.

Heti’s descendants were Malyavan, Sumali and Mali. Kaikasi (daughter of Yatudhana-Rakshasa Sumali) married Vishrava (son of the pious Rishi Pulastya). Their children were Ravana, Kumbhakarana, Surphanka and Vibhishana [Ref: Ramayana 7.4-5, 7.9]. They and their descendants were the Kaikasi-Rakshasas or simply Rakshasas.

Thus, Ravana was a son of a Brahmin father and a Yatudhana-Rakshasa (hybrid descendant of a Pishacha and a Rakshasa) mother.

Source: 'Essence of the Fifth Veda' by Gaurang Damani page 14.