# Name of Ravana's brothers and his sons killed in the Ramayana war?

Tags: ramayana, war

Ravana has many brothers and sons as per [the answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9554/12071) of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9553).  I want to know the main characters who were killed by lord Rama's army in the war as per below list. If any other army of lord Rama is there whose name is missing in below but had killed any of them then please add it.

I will be happy and interest with only of Ravan's brothers and his own sons excluding all sons of his brothers .

- How many of them were killed by lord Rama?
- How many of them were killed by lord Lakshman?
- How many of them were killed by lord Hanuman?
- Any of them were killed by Sugriva?
- Any of them were killed by Angad?
- Any of them were killed by Jambavan?
- Any of them were killed by Nala?
- Any of them were killed by Nila?

Comment: Vanara warriors killed many and Rama Lakshmana killed too many. This looks like a too-broad question. You can specify the Rakshasa and by whom he was killed. To answer this, we have to go through total Yuddha Kanda.  i.e., **66 chapters covering the war**. btw, the answer you linked has some flaws. Ahiravan is not mentioned in Ramayana and also Brahmanda purana.

Comment: I understood your question. Even if we consider people slain by main characters like Rama, Lakshmana etc., that would be many. I suggest you to add Rakshasas names and ask who killed him. By this, we can minimise the answers.

Comment: Ravana had 10 brothers and 3 sisters as said in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19449/5212) opposed to the accepted answer.. I think you haven't understood my comment. Rama, Hanuman, Angada, Jambavan killed many Rakshasas. If you give the names of the Rakshasas instead asking how many Rakshasas did Rama, Lakshmana etc., killed. That would add up to half of the Ravana army.

Comment: @KailashChandraPolai - "But I cleaned mentioned as the main characters and only of ravan's relatives" - This thing was not clear. And you said in question that "If any other are there please add them" . Anyway my answer is community WIKI answer. anybody can contribute in it.

Comment: Is this question now limited to Ravana's real brothers and sons only? If so, then how come Virupaksha is in answer who is son of Malyavan (as per Uttarkanda)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the description of some of the demons killed by Lord Hanuman , Sugreeva and Angada from Valmiki Ramayana  Yuddha Kanda . **Lord Hanuman killed Nikumbha.Sugreeva kills Virupaksha and Angada Killing Narantaka .**

Book VI : Yuddha Kanda - Book Of War Chapter  77 -[**Nikumbha dies at the hands of Hanuma.**](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga77/yuddha_77_frame.htm)

> अथ निनदति सादिते निकुम्भे | पवनसुतेन रणे बभूव युद्धम् |
>   दशरथसुतराक्षसेन्द्रसून्वो | र्भृशतरमागतरोषयोः सुभीमम् || 6.77.23||
>
> tha ninadati saadite nikumbhe | pavanasutena raNe babhuuva yuddham
>   |
>  dasharathasutaraakShasendrasuunvo | rbhR^ishataramaagataroShayoH
>   subhiimam || 6-77-23||
>
> Then, while the roaring **Nikumbha was killed in battle by Hanuma**, there
>   ensued an exceedingly terrific struggle between the enraged Rama and
>   Makaraksha, son of Khara, a ruler of demons.

---

VI : Yuddha Kanda - Book Of  war  - Chapter  96 - [**Sugreeva kills Virupaksha.**](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga96/yuddha_96_frame.htm)

> विनाशितं प्रेक्ष्य विरूपनेत्रं | महाबलन् तन् हरिपार्थिवेन | 
>  बलन्
>   समस्तन् कपिराक्षसानाम् | उन्मत्तगङ्गाप्रतिमं बभूव || 6-96-36||
>
> vinaashitaM prekShya virUpanetraM | mahaabalan tan haripaarthivena
>   |
>  balan samastan kapiraakShasaanaam | unmattaga~NgaapratimaM
>   babhUva || 6-96-36 ||
>
> Beholding that mighty **Virupaksha killed by Sugreeva**, the army of
>   monkeys and demons together looked like the agitated river of
>   Ganga.Beholding that mighty Virupaksha killed by Sugreeva, the army of
>   monkeys and demons together looked like the agitated river of Ganga.

---

VI : Yuddha Kanda - Book Of  Chapter - 97 -Verse 33 -[**Mahodara killed by Sugreeva.**](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga97/yuddha_97_frame.htm)

> लग्नमुत्कर्षतः खड्गन् खड्गेन कपिकुञ्जरः |
>  जहार सशिरस्त्राणन्
>   कुण्डलोपहितन् शिरः || 6.97.33||
>
> lagnamutkarShataH khaDgan khaDgena kapiku~njaraH 
>  jahAra
>   sashirastrANan kuNDalopahitan shiraH |  ||6-97-33||
>
> Even while Mahodara was extracting his sword which had got struck in
>   the shield, **Sugreeva severed with his own sword, Mahodara's head,**
>   which was adorned with ear-rings and helmet.

---

Book VI : Yuddha Kanda - Book Of War - Chapter - 69 - [**Angada Killing Narantaka .**](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga69/yuddha_69_frame.htm)

> थदान्तरिक्षे त्रिदश उत्तमानाम् | वन ओकसाम् चैव महा प्रणादः |
>  बभूव
>   तस्मिन् निहते अग्र्य वीरे |नर अन्तके वालि सुतेन सम्ख्ये || 6.69.95||
>
> thadaantarikSe tridasha uttamaanaam | vana okasaam caiva mahaa
>   praNaadaH | babhuuva tasmin nihate agrya viire |nara antake vaali
>   sutena samkhye || 6-69-95 ||
>
> When that **Narantaka of great prowess was killed by Angada** in
>   battle, the chiefs of celestials and the monkeys too then emitted a
>   great roar of triumph in the sky.

---

Book VI : Yuddha Kanda - Book Of War -
Chapter  67 - Verse 177 - [**Lord Rama Kills Kumbhakarna**](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga67/yuddha_67_frame.htm)

> स देवलोकस्य तमो निहत्य |सूर्यो यथा राहुमुखाद्विमुक्तः |
>  तथा
>   व्यभासीद्धरिसैन्यमध्ये | निहत्य रामो यधि कुम्भकर्णम् || 6-67-177||
>
> sa devalokasya tamo nihatya | suuryo yathaa raahumukhaadvimuktaH |
>   tathaa vyabhaasiiddharisainyamadhye | nihatya raamo yadhi kumbhakarNam
>   || 6-67-177||
>
> **Having destroyed Kumbhakarna in battle, that Rama shone in the midst of the army of monkeys,** in the same way as the sun shines in the
>   midst of the celestial world, having destroyed darkness, duly getting
>   delivered from the mouth of Rahu.

---

Book V : Sundara Kanda - Sarga 47 - [**Lord Hanumana kills Aksha (Ravana's own son)**](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga47/sundara_47_frame.htm)

> निहत्य तम् वज्र सुत उपम प्रभम् | कुमारम् अक्षम् क्षतज उपम ईक्षणम् |
>
> तत् एव वीरो अभिजगाम तोरणम् | कृत क्षणः काल इव प्रजा क्षये || ५-४७-३८
>
> Killing that Aksha, possessing a lustre equal to that of Jayanta the son of Indra the lord of celestials and having his eyes resembling blood, the heroic Hanuma reached the same archy door way again, like Yama the lord of death expecting in a moment any mortal getting destroyed by him.

---

Book VI : Yuddha Kanda - Sarga 91 - [**Lakshmana kills Indrajit or Meghanada (Ravana's own son)**](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga91/yuddha_91_frame.htm)

> रुधिरक्लिन्नगात्रस्तु लक्ष्मणः शुभलक्षणः |
>
> बभूव हृष्टस्तं हत्वा शक्रजेतारमाहवे || ९१-६-१
>
> Lakshmana, endowed with auspicious bodily marks, whose limbs were
>   drenched in blood, felt rejoiced on having killed Indrajit in combat.

Comment: @KailashChandraPolai - Yes added the shloka in answer. Will update the answer and will add more content  later on. :-)

Comment: What about Khara, Dushana - Ravana's other cousin brothers, who were killed by Rama in Aranya Kanda. Plus Ravana's own sons Atikaya, Trishira and Prahasta, who were killed by Lakshmana, Rama and Nila respectively.

In other versions of Ramayana, especially Adhyatma, Ahiravana was killed by Panchamukhi Hanuman by stomping on him.

Comment: Plus Devantaka was also killed by Hanuman.

Comment: Questioner wants only Ravana's real brothers and his own sons..Prahasta was son of Sumali..if there was some other Prahasta, u can add in this answer as it's wiki..but first which verse says he is son/brother of Ravana and then who killed him...

Comment: @YDS What is real brother? Is there a fake brother? Do you mean born of same father and mother? and also own son? There is no need of mentioning own or adopted. Son is enough. If only brothers born of same mother or father and mother are real brothers? What is the relation between Rama and Lakshmana? Aren't they real brothers?

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar Khara, Dushana etc., are not killed in the war between Ravana and Rama. They are killed much before. If you want to add, you can give them in the answer. It is a community wiki. This answer is only limited to Valmiki Ramayana not other versions.

Comment: Yes Khara and Dushana were not in the war. And @YDS Prahasta was very much Ravana's son. Ravana had a lot of sons - Meghnad, Trishira, Prahasta, Atikaya, Akshaya, Devantaka, Narantaka. Remember he also didn't have only Mandodari as his wife.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I mentioned Adhyatma Ramayana since it was mentioned in the comment section, but I don't think the questioner has specified only Valmiki's Ramayana. Still, taking V's Ramayana as the benchmark, I added Adh. Ramayana in the comments.

Comment: @YDS you want to know who killed Prahasta - Ravana's son. Please read Valmiki Ramayana the entire Sarga 58. It describes in vivid descriptive details the battle between Nila and Prahasta. But I will quote one verse, the killing blow -

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar A community wiki answer should be consistent and should follow only one thing and should not contradict. That is why I said this answer is limited to Valmiki Ramayana not the question and the OP seems to look from Valmiki Ramayanam because he accepted the answer. and don't add verses in the comments. They should go in the answer. Post your own answer or add it in the existing answer. Comments are neither for answering.nor for discussion.

Comment: नीलेन कपिमुख्येन विमुक्ता महती शिला | 
बिभेद बहुधा घोरा प्रहस्तस्य शिरस् तदा || ६-५८-५४ 

Then, that huge and terrific rock hurled by Nila the leader of the monkeys broke Prahasa's head into myriad pieces.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma "Ravana sends Aksha, his own son" this is even mentioned in the link which i gave in answer..this is to differentiate from his brother/sister's son..and real brother means who is not cousin brother..Arkaprabha: Prahasta was son of Sumali but there might be another Raksha too who was Ravana's son..u should validate who was killed by Nila... Ravana's son or Sumali's son..

Comment: @YDS its obvious that I mean Ravana's son Prahasta when I am answering with respect to Ravana's sons/brothers. Plus please read Valmiki Ramayan Sarga 58, you'll get your answers

Comment: @YDS Someone who isn't a cousin is called "own brother", not "real brother".

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar is it mentioned in sarga 58 that Prahasta was son of Ravana? One Prahasta was Army general and fought against many including Aranyak, Mandhata and Kartvirya Arjuna...this was not Ravana's son.. However there may be other individual with same name.. That's why i said give source which says that the one who was killed by Nila was son of Ravana..

Comment: Nikumbha was ravan's nephew not his son. He was his brothers son.

Comment: @TheLogicalFanatic.- The original question is edited now. This is the the answer of the original question"Whom did Hanumana killed" Also note that this isn community Wiki answer.