# How many sons did Ravana have?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

Ravana had six brothers and two sisters: I know about him but how many sons of Ravana are Except Indrajit?

Comment: Do you want to know the names of other five sons?

Comment: Take a look at [Ravana - Who were his parents and siblings?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9553/277).

Comment: @Pandya yes according to this I know their names https://sladeviper777.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/lord-ravanas-family-tree/

Comment: ok. Then do you just want to know the total number of sons (i.e digit)?

Comment: yes, if possible then some information also about sons of Ravana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ravana had 7 (maybe 6) sons including Indrajit. However I won't be including Indrajit in my answer.

1. #### Atikaya

   Valmiki Ramayana Yuddha Kanda Sarga 71

   > tasyaasiidviiryavaanputro raavaNapratimo raNe |
   >   vRiddhasevii shrutadharaH sarvaastraviduShaam varaH || 6-71-28
   >
   > To him, there is a valiant son, equal to Ravana in combat, who serves elders, holding that which is heard from them and skilled in the use of weaponry.”
   >
   > ashvapRiShThe rathe naage khaDge dhanuShi karShaNe |
   >   bhede saantve cha daane cha naye mantre cha saMmataH || 6-71-29
   >
   > He is respected for his counsel, for his rides on the backs of horses and elephants, for his drawing out of the sword and the bow, for his strategy winning over to his side by sowing dissension, negotiation and bribery and for his steering capacity of an army.
   >
   > yasya baahum samaashritya laNkaa bhavati nirbhayaa |
   >   **tanayam dhaanyamaalinyaa atikaayamimam viduH** || 6-71-30
   >
   > **He is Atikaya, the son of Dhanyamali**. Lanka is feeling fearless, by resting on his arm.
2. #### Aksha

   Sundara Kanda Sarga 47

   > senaa patiin panca sa tu pramaapitaan |
   >   hanuumataa saanucaraan savaahanaan |
   >   samiikShya raajaa samara uddhata unmukham |
   >   **kumaaram akSham** prasamaikShata akShatam || 5-47-1
   >
   > Hearing and sustaining that the five army-generals along with their
   >   followers and vehicles were disposed off by Hanuma, Ravana looked at **Aksha, his son**, violent in combat and who was inclined to fighting as well as sitting in front of him.
3. #### Trishira,
4. #### Devantaka
5. #### Narantaka

   Yuddha Kanda Sarga 69

   > shrutvaa **trishiraso** vaakyam **deva antaka nara antakau** |
   >   atikaayasH ca tejasvii babhuuvur yuddha harShitaaH || 6-69-9
   >
   > Hearing the words of **Trishira; Devantaka, Narantaka** and the energetic Atikaya were rejoiced of war.
   >
   > tato aham aham iti evam garjanto nairR^ita R^iShabhaaH |
   >   **raavaNasya sutaa viiraaH** shakra tulya paraakramaaH || 6-69-10
   >
   > **Then, the brave Ravana's sons**, whose prowess was equal to Indra and the foremost of demons, roared asserting their superiority saying "I will lead, I will lead!

Regarding Prahasta is it unclear whether he is Ravana's son, or just an army general.

Comment: The name is Aksha Kumara and not Akshaya Kumara. Put bold only where you want to emphasize. There's no need to emphasize on whole shloka. It's confusing and not needed.

Comment: Also, don't put everything in italics.

Comment: For me to distinguish between shloka and translation is confusing unless one of them is in italics.

Comment: Italics, bold should not be used for distinguishing. They should be used for emphasis. Putting everyting in bold or italics doesn't look good for readers. Actually, we are only required to provide English translations. Sanskrit is not required.